# Disable custom element in Polymer from being clicked

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, custom-element

What is the best way to disable a custom-element from being clicked (e.g. while it is in an animation state or just because it should be disabled for the user). Meaning no input events like "click"/"tap" should be fired and links disabled.

I want to disable the whole element including other paper-elements, not just paper-button etc. For this I know there is the "disabled" attribute.

Is it best to use `CSS`with `pointer-events`? Or is there any other way working for all browser?

[enter link description here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/)

Comment: I've used pointer-events none like you said, it does the trick.. I guess if you want you can also set a property to be sure that your events are not dispatched..

Comment: Give an example code that you want to disable. For Polymer, most of the elements have a disabled attribute, which you could bind value in a function `this.disable=true` will disable all element which has `disabled="{{disable}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, I am doing it now the following way, works fine:

In custom-styles

```
  :host([disabled]) {
    color: #a8a8a8;
    cursor: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

In properties

```
      disabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        notify: true,
        reflectToAttribute: true
      }
```

In Code

```
       this.disabled = false;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! reflectToAttribute was the thing my code was missing...